# How to retry using axios-retry for POST request on 5XX error

Tags: npm, post, axios, yarnpkg, axios-retry

Here is my implementation-

```
import axiosRetry from 'Axios-retry'

axiosRetry(axios, { retries: 3 });

axios.post('http://localhost:3005/post',{name: "abc"}) // The first request fails and the second returns 'ok'
  .then(result => {
    result.data; // 'ok'
  });
```

But retry doesn't work because **POST** is a [Idempotent](https://github.com/softonic/axios-retry/blob/3822205c6d2efc8eaa6a67d000fe7509bdde99b3/es/index.mjs#L19) request, *So how can I retry POST method using axios-retry for 5XX*?